# Azure blob stoarge uploading file takes more time

Tags: c#, performance, azure-blob-storage

I am using azure blob storage for uploading files. I have used the **PutLock** method. but that also takes 2 minutes for uploading 17 MB files.is there any way to upload files very fastly with programmatical way.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to upload files very fastly with programmatical way.

There is a [Microsoft Azure Storage Data Movement Library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement#microsoft-azure-storage-data-movement-library-120) designed for high-performance uploading, downloading and copying Azure Storage Blob and File. For quickly uploading a blob, you can use it and follow this [guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement#upload-a-blob).

Here is a code example and tested by myself, it takes around 25s to upload a 63MB file into azure blob storage:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //use stop watch to calculate the uploading time.
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew(); 

            string storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=xxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
            CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);

            CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test2");
            blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();

            // the file being uploaded is about 63MB in size
            string source_path = @"F:\temp\postman.zip";

            CloudBlockBlob destBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob111.zip");

            TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 5;
            // Setup the transfer context and track the upload progress
            SingleTransferContext context = new SingleTransferContext();
            context.ProgressHandler = new Progress<TransferStatus>((progress) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bytes uploaded: {0}", progress.BytesTransferred);
            });
            // Upload a local blob
            var task = TransferManager.UploadAsync(
                source_path, destBlob, null, context, CancellationToken.None);
            task.Wait();

            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"it takes about {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} milliSeconds");

            Console.WriteLine("the upload is completed");
            Console.ReadLine();

       }
```

The test result:

[image]

Comment: Hai , Thank you for your response.i tried this 

I have used this code for uploading .it takes more than 2 minutes for upload for 17 MB.

if I remove this line destBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; it is uploading fastly with  50 sec.but i want this line for uploading.may i need to change any configuration in azure portal???

Please find out my code here
https://github.com/ArulPushpam/Azure-Blob-Storage/blob/master/Mytest

Comment: @arulpushpam, I can think of 2 ways to set the ContentType. Method 1. After the image is uploaded to blob storage, you can use [storage explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows), then manually change the content-type. Method 2.After the image is uploaded, you can use code to fetch and change the content-type property of the blob.

Comment: I can't change the image content type manually.i have uploaded a lot of files here. I didn't retrieve the attachments using code .i am using the azure path for getting attachments.so here I can't change the content type while retrieving.is there any new way for uploading fastly

Comment: @arulpushpam, do you mind sharing the big size image? I don't have such image whose size is 17MB. And I also note that you read the image as stream first, then upload the stream. Why not directly upload the image without using stream?

Comment: in my side i can't send the sourcepath.so why i read a file as stream.

Comment: @arulpushpam, then can you share an image?

Comment: this is my image url https://github.com/ArulPushpam/Azure-Blob-Storage/blob/master/testimage.jpg

Comment: @arulpushpam, I used the same code with you, it just takes 7s to upload the image. I suspect it may be due to the network. Can you try with different values for `TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations` ?

Comment: yeah sure.
   TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 10;
i will go with this value.will update you

Comment: whatever I use these options.it takes more than 1 minutes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206889/discussion-between-ivan-yang-and-arul-pushpam).